# How to set a number to the variable when make instance?

Tags: ios, swift

I know you can set a variable to String object like the below.

```
var str = String("I bought \(num) CDs")
```

Then can I set a number like this?

*Before*

```
var stageViewController: StageBaseViewController?

switch stage {

    case 1:
        stageViewController = Stage01Controller()
    case 2:
        stageViewController = Stage02Controller()
    case 3:
        stageViewController = Stage03Controller()
    case 4:
        stageViewController = Stage04Controller()
    case 5:
        stageViewController = Stage05Controller()
    //...

}
```

*after*

```
stageViewController = Stage\(stage)Controller()
```

Comment: if you want get controller you can use Identifier

        `let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " Stage\(10)Controller()") `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store all the functions that produces your VCs in an array and use the index to access them:

```
let myVCs: [() -> UIViewController] = [
    Stage01Controller.init,
    Stage02Controller.init,
    Stage03Controller.init,
    Stage04Controller.init,
    Stage05Controller.init,
]
```

And then using `stage`, we can

```
let stageController = myVCs[stage]()
```

However, have you considered any other way of doing this? Having 5 stage controllers looks like code smell. Maybe you can create one `StageController` and pass data about the particular stage to it? And then you can write the logic of how to display the data in `StageController`?

Comment: Clever way to avoid creating all of the view controllers up front to put them in an array. But definitely agree that having 5 separate controllers may not be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have 100 stages for this app. These viewcontrollers already inherits from super class "StageBaseController" as you said. Is it not good way?

Comment: @bao Can you tell me what those stage controllers have in common? For example, if your stages are displaying a `UIImage` each, then instead of having hundreds of stages, have hundreds of `UIImage`s and pass them to one single VC.

Comment: @Sweeper these stage have some views of game objects (almost UIImageView and UIButton). But depends on the stage, the number of them changes. Stage1 has 10 images and 3 buttons, but Stage2 has other 20 images and 5 buttons. These common things are game clear view, game over view, preference view and functions for screen transition. So I write them in StageBaseViewController.

Comment: @bao Then create a data structure that represents what the stages display. This data structure should have the minimum amount of information needed to recreate the stage. Then `StageBaseViewController` will use the data to recreate the stage. So instead of storing a `UIImageView` in your data structure, you can just store the file name of the image as a string.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried to use a data structure but I'll try it. If you know good reference, please tell me. Thank you!

Comment: @bao The skill modelling your data takes a lot of practice. I learned it through lots and lots of practice, not some reference book/resource.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately this cannot be done in `Swift` because `\()` can be used only in String.